# Steps to implement LDAP on my website using PHP

Tags: php, ldap

Can any one please let me explain step by step implementation for LDAP on my site using PHP

Answer (score 3):

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/ldap.installation.php

> LDAP support in PHP is not enabled by default. You will need to use the --with-ldap[=DIR] configuration option when compiling PHP to enable LDAP support. DIR is the LDAP base install directory. To enable SASL support, be sure --with-ldap-sasl[=DIR] is used, and that sasl.h exists on the system.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have PHP's LDAP extension installed, as @The MYYN suggests. To implement an LDAP-based authentication mechanism I recommend that you use [Zend_Auth and its adapter for LDAP](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.auth.adapter.ldap.html). Further operations can be handled with [Zend_Ldap](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.ldap.introduction.html).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your question is still not answered, because you did not choose an answer.

So if you want to know how to authenticate a user, you can do it this way :

```
$userFound = false;

$ds = ldap_connect('my.ldap.com');
if ($ds)
{
    // Anonymous bind
    ldap_bind($ds);
    // Search the DN of the user
    $searchRes = ldap_search($ds, 'ou=people,dc=my_company,dc=com', 'uid=your_user_uid');

    $info = ldap_get_entries($ds, $searchRes);

    // If the search returned at least one result, try to bind to the server
    // using the DN you just get, and the password provided by you user
    if ($info['count'] < 0)
        $userFound = ldap_bind($ds, $info[0]['dn'], $password);

    ldap_close($ds);
}

var_dump($userFound);
```

Note that, as miku said, you have to install LDAP. It is not installed by default.